# Syntax error on the definition of a function in python which seems valid

Tags: python, sh

When I define a function in this code:

```
def is_palindrome(seq):
    s=seq[::-1]
    if s==seq:
         return True
    else:
         return False

myfile=open('palindrome.txt','r')
for line in myfile:
    if is_palindrome(line.srtrip()):
        print(line,end='')
myfile.close()
```

It returns this error message in my console:

```
./palindrome.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./palindrome.py: line 1: `def is_palindrome(seq):'
```

and I don't know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 13):

You're executing your script as a *sh script. You should do `python palindrome.py`

Indeed, the error message you get is typically an error of *sh script... When you're calling the script via `./palindrome.py`, it executes it with the first interpreter which matches. It seems to be a *sh interpretor here, from your Linux environnement.

To avoid that, **the best method** is to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the first line of your Python script, which'll force your command line to use the Python interpretor instead of your *sh interpretor.

*NB: *sh here represented any derivate of sh: bash, zsh, etc.*

Comment: Or add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line. This will tell the shell which interpreter to use. Note the `env` version is preferred since it works with multiple Python versions, virtualenv, etc.

Comment: You don't need the `./` if you pass the file to the python interpreter

Comment: Actually, using ./ is the right thing to do. Otherwise it may accidentally run a system command if they share the same name. Consider a script called 'test'. `./test` will do the right thing whereas `test` will not. Plus, '.' is not always on a user's `PATH`.

Comment: @SeanPerry: Actually, I believe he's referring to the form `python ./test` vs `python test`. In that case, you don't need the `./` because the shell will not attempt to execute `test` directly at all, it will simply be passed to Python as an argument.

Comment: @SeanPerry Actually, with the `python` before, it's passed as an argument to the python program (in the classic `argv` tab), so it'll be used as a file path.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using the hashbang. That way a user can *pick* whether to use `./` or invoke using `python`.

Comment: Good point @MaximeLorant. I prefer to use ./ to be explicit. Sometimes  when testing we get blinders on and fail to notice the simple thing like not running the code we think we are.

Comment: Of course, as the Python shell says: `>>> import this [...] Explicit is better than implicit.` :)

Comment: Thank sir, i did like that, and it work :), i really thoght that it will work if i use shell excute command :

Answer (score 0):

Indentation?

```
def is_palindrome(seq):
    s=seq[::-1]
    if s==seq:
        return True
   else:
        return False
```

Comment: yes, my code like this, sorry, first time i write a topic and i dont know how to format paragraph :)

Comment: The code you post is wrong and what you are trying to tell isn't very clear.

Comment: Probably because the author forget to put the code in a "code block" at the first time. Be careful on that type of question, it's common.